# save a txt file in Python, some tips to improve my code

Tags: python, performance, coding-style

first of all, sorry for this easy question. I know these questions are really basic. I need to save a txt file in Python 2.7 with several rows. I need to ask some suggestions to improve my basic code.

this is a basic example

```
file_out = open("..//example//test.text", "w")

for p in range(10):
    ID = str(p)
    A = p*10
    B = p+10
    C = p-10
    D = p+p
    E = p*2
    file_out.write("s% %s %s %s s% s%" % (ID,A,B,C,D,E)+ "\n")
file_out.close()
```

my question are:

- i have this Error Message, and i did'n find a way to resolve

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
    ValueError: incomplete format
  ```
- my element to save (ex: ID,A,B,C,D,E) are several (30 elements), and
  i use a long line of s%. IS there an elegant way and compact to code
  this line?.
- i wish to save also an head (ex: ID,A,B,C,D,E). What is the best way
  to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo

```
file_out.write("%s %s %s %s %s %s" % (ID,A,B,C,D,E)+ "\n")
```

or

```
   file_out.write("%s %s %s %s %s %s\n" % (ID,A,B,C,D,E))
```

or

```
file_out.write(" ".join(["%s" %i for i in [A, B, C, D, E]]))
```

Comment: Thank. I didn't understand how i can create a header (the first line of my txt file(

Answer (score 3):

> ValueError: incomplete format

You wrote half of the `%s` formats as `s%`. The percent sign goes first.

> my element to save (ex: ID,A,B,C,D,E) are several (30 elements), and i use a long line of s%. IS there an elegant way and compact to code this line?.

```
' '.join(str(x) for x in [p, p*10, p+10, p-10, p+p, p*2])
```

Comment: @johan thanks. To save an Header i need to type a new line before ' '.join(str(x) for x in [p, p*10, p+10, p-10, p+p, p*2])?

Answer (score 1):

`%` first, *then* the specifier.

```
%s
```

Also:

```
print >>file_out, ' '.join(...)
```

Also, [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have a few syntax errors. Check your formatting string.

```
file_out = open("..//example//test.text", "w")

for p in range(10):
    ID = str(p)
    A = p*10
    B = p+10
    C = p-10
    D = p+p
    E = p*2
    file_out.write("%s %s %s %s %s %s" % (ID,A,B,C,D,E) + "\n")
file_out.close()
```